# show progress of a nested function triggered by ipywidget

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets, tqdm

I have an input field, button and output placed in a Jupyter notebook using a function. On the button there is an on_click that will trigger a function that will plot a graph in the output. However, this function is using another function to generate the data for the graph. Now I want to show the progress of this 2nd function in the output. How would I go about doing this?
I looked into using tqdm, but then I just get the initial progress bar in the log (which doesn't update), not in the notebook cell

```
from random import randint
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from tqdm.notebook import tqdm
from ipywidgets import Layout, Button, Box, FloatText, Label, Output

def form_plot_simulation():
    button = Button(
    description='Plot simulation results',
    disabled=False,
    tooltip='Plot simulation results')
    
    global simulations_field
    simulations_field = FloatText(value='10')
    
    global out_plot_sim
    out_plot_sim = Output()
    button.on_click(plot_data)
    
    form_items = [
        Box([simulations_field]),
        Box([button]),
        Box([out_plot_sim])
    ]
    form_plot_sim = Box(form_items, layout=Layout(
        display='flex',
        flex_flow='column',
        border='solid 2px',
        align_items='stretch',
        width='600px'))
    return form_plot_sim

def plot_data(b):
    simulations = int(simulations_field.value)
    data = simulate_test(simulations)
    
    plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
    plt.plot(data)
    
    with out_plot_sim:
        out_plot_sim.clear_output()
        plt.show()

def simulate_test(simulations):
    data = []
    for i in tqdm(range(0,simulations)):
        datapoint = randint(0,10)
        data.append(datapoint)

    return data
```

The cell in the notebook just has this code to display the form:

```
display(form_plot_simulation())
```

EDIT: Note: I hate the usage of global, but didn't know how to pass the field value on in the functions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have tqdm here, but you can adapt your example. I used a functools partial to bundle another argument to the `on_click` function.

```py
from random import randint
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
# from tqdm.notebook import tqdm
from ipywidgets import Layout, Button, Box, FloatText, Label, Output
import time
import functools

def form_plot_simulation():
    button = Button(
    description='Plot simulation results',
    disabled=False,
    tooltip='Plot simulation results')
    
    global simulations_field
    simulations_field = FloatText(value='10')
    
    global out_plot_sim
    out_plot_sim = Output()
    output_progress = Output(height='20px')
    button.on_click(functools.partial(plot_data, output_progress))
    
    form_items = [
        simulations_field,
        button, 
        output_progress, 
        out_plot_sim,
    ]
    form_plot_sim = Box(form_items, layout=Layout(
        display='flex',
        flex_flow='column',
        border='solid 2px',
        align_items='stretch',
        width='600px'))
    return form_plot_sim

def plot_data(output_widget, b):
    simulations = int(simulations_field.value)
    data = simulate_test(simulations, output_widget)
    
    plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
    plt.plot(data)
    
    with out_plot_sim:
        out_plot_sim.clear_output()
        plt.show()

def simulate_test(simulations, output_widget):
    data = []
    for i in range(0,simulations):
        datapoint = randint(0,10)
        data.append(datapoint)
        time.sleep(0.1)
        with output_widget:
            output_widget.clear_output()
            print(i)

    return data
```